# Disable/Hide/Remove Docs menu in Apache Airflow GUI

Tags: flask, airflow, flask-appbuilder

I have installed Airflow in my Ubuntu system and trying to deploy Airflow to production. I would like to turn off the menu **Docs** on the UI (browser).

I was reading setting permissions on the menus here [access-control](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html) but it is hard to turn off this menu for each role. I am curious to know if we can Disable/Hide/Remove Docs menu from the root.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's no one-click way to turn it off globally. I wonder why it's hard to turn it off for each role? The only way to truly perform this in one action is to query the metastore directly and remove the `menu access on Docs` permission from all roles using a single SQL query.

Assuming you don't have too many roles, it takes just a few clicks in the UI. First you'll need Admin permissions and go to Security -> List Roles. In there, edit each role and remove the `menu access on Docs` permission.